# Which is the correct C# infinite loop, for (;;) or while (true)?

Tags: c#, infinite-loop

Back in my C/C++ days, coding an "infinite loop" as

```
while (true)
```

felt more natural and seemed more obvious to me as opposed to

```
for (;;)
```

An encounter with [PC-lint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pcl.htm) in the late 1980's and subsequent best practices discussions broke me of this habit. I have since coded the loops using the `for` control statement. Today, for the first time in a long while, and perhaps my first need for an infinite loop as a C# developer, I am facing the same situation. Is one of them correct and the other not?

Comment: Four identical answers in under two minutes. Not bad.

Comment: I swear this is an exact duplicate, but SO's search engine ignores "for" and "while" as common words, so I can't find the original. ;-)

Comment: @Ben - I agree there has to be an original to this, however I spent 20 minutes searching for it to no avail!

Comment: I agree with all of you that "while ( true )" is easier to read and more obvious. I'm interested in best practices and established standards.

Comment: @Bob: As I said in my answer, this has always been the convention that I have seen people adopt in C#. I have seen empty for loops in other languages, but in C# it always seems to be while(true).

Comment: @Adam - the evidence weighs overwhelmingly in your favor! At this point, I tend to go into a long-winded diversion using the word "ain't" as an example of how usage infers acceptance. Suffice to say that while ( true ) appears to be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Bob: while(true) is the best practice for creating infinite loops if there ever was a practice that required such...  The for(;;) is difficult to read and leads to way too much confusion.  while(1) is not something that will work in C#.

Comment: You could avoid the whole religious argument by unrolling your infinite loop. Shouldn't take long...

Comment: @RSolberg - good point. I'm editing things accordingly.

Comment: ... Allen beat me to it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why is for(;;) better in C/C++?

Comment: @Vilx as I recall it, old compilers used to write more efficient code with for(;;) than while(1). I'm sure that any decent modern compiler will output pretty much identical code.

Comment: *Spaces* excessive usage. I'd use like this: `while (true)` and `for (; ; )`

Comment: Building on Stephen and Serhio's comments:

1. `while(true)` requires a condition. `for(;;)` is therefore a better representation for infinite loops which repeat unconditionally.
2. Old unoptimizing compilers may have actually evaluated the `(true)` as it looped.
3. C is a minimalist language from the days of teletypes, 300 baud terminals, and 1-char variable names. In an environment where every key stroke counts, `for(;;)` is quite a bit shorter than `while(true)`.

Comment: As of C/C++, some compiles can produce a "conditional expression is constant" warning in case of while(true).

Comment: "Which approach is faster and which is more memory efficient" is probably a better way to phrase the question

Answer (score 133, accepted):

```
while(true)
{

}
```

Is always what I've used and what I've seen others use for a loop that has to be broken manually.

Comment: @RSolberg - it was a toss-up between the two similar responses offered within seconds of one another. Adam's follow-up comment led me to accepting an answer based on usage rather than convention.

Comment: while and for can both be broken manually

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer does not answer the question. The correct answer is "both are correct".

Comment: @Loadmaster: That depends on your definition of "correct" (or, rather what sort of "correctness" you're after).

Answer (score 345):

The C# compiler will transform both

```
for(;;)
{
    // ...
}
```

and

```
while (true)
{
    // ...
}
```

into

```
{
    :label
    // ...
    goto label;
}
```

The CIL for both is the same. Most people find `while(true)` to be easier to read and understand. `for(;;)` is rather cryptic.

#### Source:

I messed a little more with [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector), and I compiled both loops with the "Optimize Code" on in Visual Studio.

Both loops compile into (with .NET Reflector):

```
Label_0000:
    goto Label_0000;
```

[Raptors should attack soon.](http://xkcd.com/292/)

Comment: yup, just double checked, its all the same IL code, this should be the accepted answer IMO :)

Comment: shame you weren't first.  this is complete, researched, and correct.

Comment: +1 for the xkcd reference

Comment: + 1: for taking the time to prove it all out...

Comment: To be pedantic, the compiler does *not* transform one statement form into the other; rather, it generates identical code for both statements. That code is identical to a `goto` statement, btw, which is no surprise.

Comment: and then the goto is translated to a jmp instruction..

Comment: so obviously `goto LOOP` is the correct C# infinite loop :)

Comment: @Dustin: Premature optimization ... you know the rest :P

Comment: While very interesting, technically it is not an answer to the question. If for(;;) was a fraction faster, would we recommend using it?

Comment: The question wasn't about speed either. it was about if it is correct or not. I said that `while(true)` may be easier to read and to understand by most people.

Answer (score 61):

I think that this may be easier to read and is definitely the standard for use in C#:

```
while(true)
{
   //Do My Loop Stuff
}
```

Comment: @voyager: 1 is not a substitute for 'true' in C#.

Comment: Note that while(1) is invalid C#: Constant 1 cannot be converted to bool

Comment: `while(1)` isn't valid in C#, since `1` is not a `bool`.

Answer (score 55):

Gasp, use:

```
while (!false)
{

}
```

OR as [jsight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1432/jsight) pointed out, you may want to be doubly sure:

```
while (!false && true)
{
}
```

Before people yell at me, it's all the same CIL code, I checked :)

Comment: Best answer ever.

Comment: while (!false && true) is half sure, while (!false || true) is doubly sure :)

Comment: You should check whether false is really false. So better write while(true == true && false == false && (!false || true))

Answer (score 37):

To rehash a couple of old jokes:

1. Don't use "`for (;;) {}`" — it makes the statement cry.
2. Unless, of course, you "`#define EVER ;;`".

Comment: Or `#define ever (;;)` which I think is more readable. `for ever {}`

Comment: I didnt think you could do a #define ever (;;) in C#, though, the joke is funny :)

Comment: Ah. I program C on OS X. I didn't know the C# preprocessor was so castrated. I'm not even sure how I started reading this question, I have C# as an ignored tag...

Comment: The C# preprocessor is not really a preprocessor, at least not in terms of what C, C++, PL/1, and even macro assemblers provide. It only allows you to enable or disable blocks of code by defining/undefining preprocessor symbols.

Comment: Or even better: `#define forever while(true)` ;)

Comment: the question is about C#, not C++, we can't #define ;;

Answer (score 28):

If you want to go old school, goto is still supported in C#:

```
STARTOVER:  
    //Do something
    goto STARTOVER;
```

For a truly infinite loop, this is the go-to command. =)

Comment: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: I upvoted this from a negative rating back to zero, but only because of its humor value. Hey, all loops get compiled into JMP assembler opcodes anyway, right?

Comment: @Loadmaster: Thanks, I was just throwing it out there as another option, not necessarily endorsing it.

Comment: -1 don't use goto in C#, nor in VB.NET: bad practice in modern language.

Comment: @serhio: Even more so is avoiding language constructs out of hand because you read something somewhere. No language element by itself is bad, it can only be used in bad ways.

Comment: @JohnFx: Yes, John, don't use goto, because you probably will use it in a bad way. take a look http://david.tribble.com/text/goto.html

Comment: @serhio: I have seen abominations against nature using just about every keyword possible. It isn't the language element, it is the programmer. In any case, as noted in my previous comment, I wasn't endorsing it. I was just including it for completeness and a tingle of humor.

Comment: @serhio: Hey, thanks for referencing my *goto* article!

Comment: @Loadmaster: Are you David?... a, ok, I see :) good work. However, you convinced not everbody.

Comment: @serhio: Yes, because most programmers are still taught the knee-jerk reaction that all gotos are evil, without being taught any of the history behind it all.

Answer (score 22):

I think `while (true)` is a bit more readable.

Answer (score 12):

In those situations where I needed a true infinite loop, I've always used

```
while(true) {...}
```

It seems to express intent better than an empty for statement.

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I have always preferred `for(;;)` precisely because it has *no* condition (as opposed to `while (true)` which has an always-true one). However, this is really a very minor style point, which I don't feel is worth arguing about either way. I've yet to see a C# style guideline that mandated or forbade either approach.

Comment: don't worth in .NET, when compiler transforms your (bad readable) *for* without condition in a *while* with condition.

Comment: @serhio: please explain what you mean by "compiler transforms ... in a `while`". As far as programmer is concerned, the compiler transforms high-level code into IL. There are no `while` (or `for`) loops in IL, only labels and gotos.

Comment: see Pierre-Alain Vigeant 's answer.

Comment: His answer can be better rephrased as simply "the compiler generates identical IL for both" (you don't really know if and when it transforms anything on AST level, and it's an implementation detail in any case).  In any case, this doesn't explain why it's "not worth it in .NET". The same is also true of C++, Java...

Answer (score 6):

I personally prefer the `for (;;)` idiom (coming from a C/C++ point of view).  While I agree that the `while (true)` is more readable in a sense (and it's what I used way back when even in C/C++), I've turned to using the `for` idiom because:

- it stands out

I think the fact that a loop doesn't terminate (in a normal fashion) is worth 'calling out', and I think that the `for (;;)` does this a bit more.

Comment: finally, using that we will wait a little more that the programs compile(compile transformation from for=>while)

Comment: @serhio: Not really. It doesn't *transform* it from `for` to `while`. For both `for (;;){}` and `while (true){}`, it generates new `while(true){}` code. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1401208/732016).

Comment: I agree because I feel like `for (;;)` declares intent more clearly. e.g., although the _action_ is clear, a `while (true)` statement looks like someone forgot to pass a variable.

Answer (score 6):

The original [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_(book)) book for C, from which C# can trace its ancestry, recommended

```
for (;;) ...
```

for infinite loops. It's unambiguous, easy to read, and has a long and noble history behind it.

**Addendum** *(Feb 2017)*

Of course, if you think that this looping form (or any other form) is too cryptic, you can always just *add a comment*.

```
// Infinite loop
for (;;)
    ...
```

Or:

```
for (;;)    // Loop forever
    ...
```

Comment: yes, but this is for C, not for C#.

Comment: It works in C#. And the C# language was derived (indirectly) from C.

Comment: 8 years later you decided update your answer. Nice

Comment: In the time of the original K&R book, C did not support booleans yet.

Answer (score 5):

It should be `while(true)` not `while(1)`, so `while(1)` is incorrect in C#, yes ;)

Answer (score 3):

Even I also say the below one is better :)

```
while(true)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of code readability `while(true)` in whatever language I feel makes more sense. In terms of how the computer sees it there really shouldn't be any difference in today's society of very efficient compilers and interpreters.

If there is any performance difference to be had I'm sure the translation to MSIL will optimise away. You could check that if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively one could say having an infinite loop is normally bad practice anyway, since it needs an exit condition unless the app really runs forever. However, if this is for a cruise missile I will accept an explicit exit condition might not be required.

Though I do like this one:

```
for (float f = 16777216f; f < 16777217f; f++) { }
```

Comment: -1: not everyone will understand your "infinite loop" reading the code, perhaps somebody could think this is a bug and try to "fix" it...

Comment: In C# `f < 16777217f` is always `false`... so this never loops.

Answer (score 2):

Both of them have the same function, but people generally prefer `while(true)`. It feels easy to read and understand...

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I'd say `for(;;)` is due the CodeDom limitations (while loops can't be declared using CodeDom and for loops are seen as the more general form as an iteration loop).

This is a pretty loose reason to choose this other than the fact that the `for` loop implementation can be used both for normal code and CodeDom generated code. That is, it can be more standard.

As a note, you can use code snippets to create a `while` loop, but the whole loop would need to be a snippet...

Answer (score 1):

I prefer slightly more "literate" code.  I'm much more likely to do something like this in practice:

```
bool shouldContinue = true;
while (shouldContinue)
{
    // ...

    shouldContinue = CheckSomething();
}
```

Comment: Ugh. Actutally, that's a `do ... while()` loop in disguise. It just took me a few seconds to see that. Had you written a `do ... while()` loop, it would have been clear immediately. -1

Comment: why waste time and resources declaring a variable when you can use while(true)? It doesn't make sense in my opinion

Comment: I find it more readable, especially if you can attach a specific meaningful flag, e.g. "while (!this.canceled)" to indicate that cancellation is the only way to stop the loop, "while (!processExited)" to indicate the loop should run until an external process goes away, etc.  There are lots of things that arguably "waste resources" that are absolutely the right thing to do in the name of ease of maintainability or readability.  "while (true)" isn't all that bad, but in my experience there's usually a better way.

Comment: +1. In most cases, a true infinite loop isn't what actually happens, and you do have some condition where you'd wish to stop (e.g. when the printer is on fire).

Comment: … in which case you should use `break`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're code-golfing, I would suggest `for(;;)`. Beyond that, `while(true)` has the same meaning and seems more intuitive. At any rate, most coders will likely understand both variations, so it doesn't really matter. Use what's most comfortable.

Comment: if you're golfing then C# is the wrong language anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Any expression that always returns true should be OK for while loop.

**Example:**

```
1==1 //Just an example for the text stated before 
true
```

Comment: Why would you ever bother forcing it to do a comparison like 1=1 when true works just as well?

Using a calculated expression feels about as silly as defining a constant like NUMBER_OF_ARMS = 598-3596;

Comment: Its an example for the answer stated before the code :)