# while(true) versus for(;;)

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is “for(;;)”  faster than “while (TRUE)”? If not, why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611246/is-for-faster-than-while-true-if-not-why-do-people-use-it)
>   [for ( ; ; ) or while ( true ) - Which is the Correct C# Infinite Loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401159/for-or-while-true-which-is-the-correct-c-infinite-loop)

Is there any appreciable difference between `while(true)` (or `while(1)`) and `for(;;)`? Would there be any reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [for ( ; ; ) or while ( true ) - Which is the Correct C# Infinite Loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401159/for-or-while-true-which-is-the-correct-c-infinite-loop) (C# for this question, but the answers also address C++)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With optimizations enabled, they will compile identically.

You should use whichever one you find more readable.

Comment: Okay, what about if optimizations are disabled?

Answer (score 6):

No. I think `for(;;)` looks nicer. But they're the same.

Also see [Is "for(;;)" faster than "while (TRUE)"? If not, why do people use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611246/is-for-faster-than-while-true-if-not-why-do-people-use-it)

Comment: Haha, is that a joke?

Comment: while (true) and for (;;) are code smells. you really need to have some proper condition to make clear what the loop is actually doing.

Comment: @R.vanTwisk Why while(true) would be a code smell? Should we use goto for infinite loop?

Comment: @EkremDÍNÇEL: He's saying you should give a stop condition to make the code more readable. E.g.
bool workCompleted = false;
while (!workCompleted) { [...] }

Comment: I like using `while (true)` more because it is more universal. Try `for (;;)` in python