# Reading txt line by line

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I am reading a text file line by line in C++. I'm using this code:

```
while (inFile)
{
getline(inFile,oneLine);
}
```

This is a text file:

```
-------

This file is a test to see 
how we can reverse the words
on one line.

Let's see how it works.

Here's a long one with a quote from The Autumn of the Patriarch. Let's see if I can say it all in one breath and if your program can read it all at once:
Another line at the end just to test.
-------
```

The problem is I can read only the paragraph starts with "Here's a long etc..." and it stops "at once:"
I couldn't solve to read all text. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: you are aware the you are overwriting the contents of `oneLine` every time that you read one line, so the only contents in `oneLine` after the while loop has terminated are of the last line.

Comment: You didn't really include much code...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct line reading idiom is:

```
std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");

for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line); )
{
    // process "line"
}
```

Or the alternative for people who don't like `for` loops:

```
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        // process "line"
    }
}
```

Note that this works as expected even if the file couldn't be opened, though you might want to add an additional check `if (infile)` at the top if you want to produce a dedicated diagnostic for that condition.

Comment: I really wish this was at the first page of every C++ book (for beginners) on the planet.

Comment: @AndréCaron: It's the first entry in my file of "frequently pasted answers", if that's any consolation.

Comment: Hahahahah "frequently pasted answers"!  I'll remember that one!

Comment: @KerrekSB: that makes it a good candidate for a vote to close as exact duplicate. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a canonical SO question that contains this canonical SO answer.

Comment: @KenBloom: There must be a thousand of those already... really, SO should have a mechanism to either create or mark existing questions as canonical, but as it stands, most of the questions are fairly obscure, while the answer is always the same...

Comment: @KerrekSB: my favorite version of this answer (and I'm biased, since I wrote it) is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6852956/197788), which demonstrates the exact same idiom in the IO library of pretty much every C-inspired language.

Comment: @KerrekSB: actually, this question is a perfect candidate for "canonical `getline()` question".