# Jquery doesn't select all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery id selector works only for the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114622/jquery-id-selector-works-only-for-the-first-element)

I want jquery to select all divs with id = box:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sizer.js"></script>
        <title>
        Design tests
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box" style="width:300px;">
        Hallo
        </div>

        <div id="box" style="width:300px;">
        Hallo
        </div>

    <script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#box").mouseenter(function(){ $(this).css("border", "1px gray outset");}).mouseleave(function(){ $(this).css("border", "none");});
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it only selects the first one. Can somebody please help me? This isn't difficult is it?

Comment: Have a stab at it people. Free reps!

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  Just because a question is basic doesn't mean it's bad.

Comment: LoL, you can't have more than one id. Use Class names instead. `<div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>` and then `$(".box")`

Comment: @Forty-Two I agree. this shouldn't be upvoted but so many downvotes... that's not necessary...

Comment: and some one favorited it already, I can smell sarcasm

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HTML allows only one element with a given id. That's the reason (internally jQuery uses [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) which returns one element).

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) :

> id = name [CS]
>
> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

If you want to select more than one element, use a class, not an id :

```
    <div class="box" style="width:300px;">
    Hallo
    </div>

    <div class="box" style="width:300px;">
    Hallo
    </div>

<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").mouseenter(function(){ $(this).css("border", "1px gray outset");}).mouseleave(function(){ $(this).css("border", "none");});
});
</script>
```

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin No : I'm past the rep cap since a long time.

Comment: yeah I know.. I wish I could get there soon..

Comment: But this answer brought me my 17th hat :)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot have more than 1 same ID, use a class instead

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sizer.js"></script>
        <title>
        Design tests
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box" style="width:300px;">
        Hallo
        </div>

        <div class="box" style="width:300px;">
        Hallo
        </div>

    <script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".box").mouseenter(function(){ $(this).css("border", "1px gray outset");}).mouseleave(function(){ $(this).css("border", "none");});
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

change your selector to `div#box` and it'll work like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#box").mouseenter(function(){ $(this).css("border", "1px gray outset");}).mouseleave(function(){ $(this).css("border", "none");});
});
```

Also note that it's bad practice to have multiple elements with the same id.
​

Answer (score 2):

The syntax $('#box') means go and select the first element whose id matches "box". What you want to do is using class instead or if you insist on using id $('div[id="box"]') will do what you want