# Do something when dynamic element is created

Tags: jquery

Via a click event, I injected an element with a custom attribute
`<div class="added" myValue="hello"></div>` to the DOM.

I wrote a generic function:

```
$('.added').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).attr('myValue') );
});
```

Doesn't work. I thought `$.each()` can handle dynamic elements?

**UPDATE to the question:**

I realize using `.each()` is the wrong approach. But what to do if I *don't want to attach an event handler* to the element. I just want to automatically do stuff to any elements of a certain class name, regardless of when they've been added to the DOM. Seems like a common use case.

Comment: Side note: since `added` *must* be unique, no need to use `$.each`, just use `$.('#added')`

Comment: [jQuery id selector works only for the first element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11114622/601179)

Comment: yeas yes thanks for pointing this out, changed the code to use classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your click event happens, do your "something" there.

```
$("#someelemt").click(function(){
    var el = $("<div class='added' myValue='hello'></div>").appendTo("#someotherelement");
    console.log(el.attr("myValue")); // <--- something
});
```

ID's must be unique, so i changed added to a class.

If you want to separate the two, have your click event trigger an event, then use event delegation to listen for it.

```
$("#someelemt").click(function(){
    var el = $("<div class='added' myValue='hello'></div>").appendTo("#someotherelement");
    el.trigger("added");
});
$(document).on("added","div",function(){
    console.log(this.getAttribute("myValue")); // <--- something
});
```

`$.each` does not work with future elements, only the elements that exist when the code is executed.

**Update for question Update**
That simply isn't possible without writing inefficient code. It would require either using DOMMutationEvents which can be inefficient, are depreciated, and are not supported in all browsers, or you can use a setInterval which is also inefficient because it would be constantly running searching the dom for new elements.

Comment: it took me a while to understand your code. Are you saying `el.trigger('added')` is a custom event? And I have to explicitly listen to this event being fired using `document.on('added'...`?

Comment: exactly, it's a custom event that you would then have to listen for. On it's own, it's pointless, but it can be used to add some separation between components

Answer (score 4):

- No, `each` doesn't handle dynamic added elements, it only apply to the element that existed in the DOM when the jQuery object created(or modified).
- `.each` function on id selector doesn't make any sense as id should be unique in the DOM.  I suggest reading this: [jQuery id selector works only for the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11114622/601179)

You must call `each` after you inject the element, or use [delegate event, like `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) with selector.

Comment: hm. but I don't want to attach an event handler to the element. I just want to automatically do stuff to any elements of a certain class name, regardless of when they've been added to the DOM.

Comment: @tim, I'm pretty sure I answered it with: _"You must call `each` after you inject the element,"_

Comment: I got that. I'm apparently using the wrong approach. Just searched google on how to select dynamic elements and all I find is stuff related to event binding.

Comment: @tim. so did you got your answer? is there still something unclear?

Comment: I don't understand why I'd have to use `delegate` or `on`, which are for events, since I'm not doing any event handling on the element. In the past, I'd simply use `.live('load'...` but since live is deprecated I'm no longer sure how to handle this.

Comment: @tim, then you need to handle it manually, when you insert the element  do what you want with it then. [`mutation events`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents-h3) are deprecated, but will do the job, check the `DomNodeInserted` event, but you shouldn't use it as it has high performance penalty.

Answer (score 3):

`$.each()` will loop through the elements that are matching your selector at the moment you are calling this method. So if you call this method before adding the elements to the DOM dynamically you cannot possibly expect that this method will return you some elements that you might hypothetically add to the DOM at some future event.

So simply call the `$.each()` function **after** you have added the elements to the DOM.

Also there seems to be an inconsistency in your code. You are using an id selector `$('#added')` which can only return a **single** element. Yes, ids must be unique through the entire DOM. So calling `.each()` on a single element hardly makes any sense unless you have some broken HTML.

Comment: yea. I excerpted this from my source code for clarity's sake, and should have used a class.

Comment: Actually jQuery could have give you the new created elements as jQuery saves internally the selector you used to create the jQuery object. but still it doesn't do so, and for good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same `id` attribute on multiple elements.  You need different IDs each time.  The ID selector `#` will only select the *first* of all of those elements, which is why it doesn't appear to be looping.

Although you really should change the ids of the other elements, this will actually still work:

```
$("[id=added]").each(...
```

Comment: the question had nothing to do with this but thanks for pointing it out.