# Change multiple elements hover background color using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got this working right now using multiple ID's and consequentially, CSS properties for each one. I'd much rather have it be automatic. All links are displayed as blocks and floated next to each other to create a tiled look. For example:

```
<a href="#" id="spacetile1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="spacetile2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="spacetile3">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" id="spacetile4">Link 4</a>

#spacetile1 {
background-color:#FFF;}

#spacetile1:hover {
background-color:#000;} .... so on and so forth for all spacetiles
```

What I'm looking to do is change the hover color based on the attribute of the default background color using some if statements to save time and accuracy of looking up corresponding branding colors.

```
if .spacetile(background-color) === #FFF
then .spacetile:hover(background-color) = #000
```

I want to do that for a set amount of colors so all I have to do is code the background color I'd like that specific tile to be and the hover background will be taken care of with the script.

I've looked into getElementById but then I'd still be using multiple ID's instead of one class and everything I've read about getElementsByClassName says that it's not supported cross-browser.

Was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for simplicity and efficiency.

Thanks!

Comment: `id` should be unique, stopped reading. [You _can_ read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11114634/601179)

Comment: For simplicity and efficiency, and cross browser selectors, use a library. jQuery is most common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a common **class**.

```
<a href="#" id="spacetile1" class="space">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="spacetile2" class="space">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="spacetile3" class="space">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" id="spacetile4" class="space">Link 4</a>
```

Using **JQuery** - [JQuery Mouse Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/)

```
$(".space").mouseover(function(){

      if($(this).css('background-color')=='#FFF000')
      {
          $(this).css('background-color','#000FFF');
      }
      //else if else if and so on...
});

$(".space").mouseout(function(){

      if($(this).css('background-color')=='#FFF000')
      {
          $(this).css('background-color','#000FFF');
      }
      //else if else if and so on...
});
```

Comment: Ali, thanks for the response. I'll try something like that out and see how it affects my page speed, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a CSS class:

```
<a href="#" id="spacetile1" class="spacetile">...</a>
<a href="#" id="spacetile2" class="spacetile">...</a>

<style>
.spacetile { background-color: #FFF; }
.spacetile:hover { background-color: #000; }
</style>
```

Comment: There are about 12 different color combinations which is why I was hoping to simplify this with one script.

Comment: @Keith using a script instead of css might make your life easier, but it won't make your user experience better.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, just looking for another solution. Not too familiar with jQuery as adeneo mentioned above but I'll look into it. 

@Christophe, I'd like to see the difference in page load times and experience. It's a very small page on an intranet so I'm not really worried about that part. Just experimenting and trying alternate solutions to figure out what works best for not only me, but my users. Experimentation!

Comment: jQuery? That's even worse ;-)

Comment: Just to answer your above comment: the smaller your page is, the more impact scripting solutions will have on performance.

Answer (score 0):

The question is built on a faulty assumption. `getElementsByClassName` is cross-browser for everything except `IE<=8`. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname (If you need to support `IE<=8`, you can fake it as below):

```
function compatGetElementsByClassName(class, tag) {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
    //Use native version
    return document.getElementsByClassName(class);
  } else {
    //Fake it
    i = 0;
    subset = (typeof tag !== 'undefined')?document.getElementsByTagName(tag):document.all;
    while (element = subset[i++]) {
      if (element.className == class) {
        //your code here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Just enter the class name and (optionally) the tag name ("a" in your case). If you don't give a tag name, it will default to `document.all` which is very inefficient.

Comment: yes, unfortunately there are users in my organization still on IE6, so i do need to support those browsers.

thanks for the solution on faking it though.