# How do disable link for particular ID

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following HTML.

```
<a id="SomeLink" title="My Title" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Click Here</a>
```

I want to disable clicking on this link. Like if there is a way in CSS or Jquery to remove "href" from this link so it is not clickable?

Comment: Why not just removing the link if you don't want clicking upon it?

Comment: I can't because that code is coming from somewhere else and I have no control over it.

Comment: Please read this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114622/jquery-id-selector-works-only-for-the-first-element/11114634#11114634

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, Removed link during on ready handler, you can also use the same while in another firing event handler as well.

```
 $(function(){
      $("#SomeLink").attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");
 });
```

OR

```
 $(function(){
      $("#SomeLink").attr("href", "#");
 });
```

Comment: This is still clickable but maybe this is really what he asked

Answer (score 1):

Bind a click handler that does nothing and disables the default action by returning false.

```
$('#SomeLink').click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Maybe this will allow you to deal with elements with duplicate IDs:

```
$('a[id=SomeLink]').click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

When you use an ID selector, jQuery uses `getElementById`, which will only find the first element with the ID. Perhaps using the generic attribute selector will bypass that and use a loop that just matches on the ID attribute. If that doesn't work, you may have to write a filter:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return this.id == 'SomeLink';
}).click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. May be because there are multiple tags with same ID?

Comment: IDs are required to be unique, you must not do that. Use classes to group related tags.

Comment: I can't control that because code is coming from somewhere else. Is there a way to parse all those IDs that are coming in that page through javascript? Then I can run a look and remove HREF from each of them.

Comment: I've added some suggestions to my answer. But you should complain to whoever is sending you the code, because it's invalid and will not work with many normal scripts.

Comment: Actually I am using SharePoint 2013 which is sending this HTML.

Comment: I don't know anything about SharePoint, but I suspect the problem is that the template author did not ensure unique IDs.

Comment: This is SharePoint's default template which is made by Microsoft.

Comment: Maybe you should ask about it on sharepoint.stackexchange.com. While Microsoft's flounting of standards is legendary, it seems unlikely they would intentionally do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.Just use attr in Jquery

```
function disbleLink(){
 $("#SomeLink").attr('href','');
 }
```

[Jsfiddle Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3cY7N/1/)

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. May be because there are multiple tags with same ID?

Comment: Can you please explain me. What do you exactly want? If you want to disable all links with different ids... that is also possible

Comment: Yes I want to disable all links having this ID. And there are multiple such IDs on that page.

Comment: Hi have done it. I have disabled all links by using same class.Have a look on demo. [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3cY7N/2/)

Comment: I don't have css class in my element.

Comment: you can use class in jquery also. As in jquery there are three types of selectors .(class),#(id) and (body/a/div/etc etc...)element

Answer (score 0):

Links cannot be disabled. Use a button instead.

```
<button disabled>click me</button>
```

If you want to prevent the default behavior when clicking a link, you can use `e.preventDefault()`

```
$("a").on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your JS.

```
$('#link').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
```

And this code in your CSS.

```
#link{
text-decoration:none;
color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that I like much better [on this site.](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?560556-How-to-disable-a-Hyper-Link&s=9364fb809dc4b542c9b99da79869f0f2&p=3892743#post3892743)

Looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#SomeLink").click(function () { 
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", .5).removeAttr("href"); 
    });
});
```

Enabling would involve setting the `href` attribute

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#SomeLink").click(function () { 
        $(this).fadeIn("fast").attr("href", "http://whatever.com/wherever.html"); 
    });
```

});