# Select DIV in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs with ID #container. 
In **first** one is class *.current-content*
`[div#container -- div.current-content]`
The **second** one is contained in class *.next-content* and contain class *current-content* 
`[div#container -- div.next-content -- div#container -- div.current-content]`
Is possible to have only one *#container* with class *.current-content* with elements from **second** *.current-content*?
Eventually how do that? 
Thanks. :)

Comment: HTML `id` attributes are supposed to be unique, so you may not have two different elements with the same id.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11114622/601179

Comment: I know, but i have div.next-content in which im loading data from next HTML file. How can i fix this?

Comment: Maybe you could pre-load the content in an iframe and copy it across from there... tbh I'm not to sure how dom elements behave cross frame though...

Answer (score 0):

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid.

from http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: Thanks. :)
Problem is, that I have html documents with same DOM [body-div#container-div.currentcontent] and i want load only #container contentfrom second one to temp div.next-content in first div#container.