# rails 4 justifiedGallery script only load the latest post with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

When i create a new post with images it works, but when i create a new post with images, justifiedGallery doesnt apply the jquery script to the previous post, why?

```
jQuery -> //when dom is ready
  $("#userindex").justifiedGallery(
    lastRow : 'justify',
    captions: false,
    randomize: false,
    rowHeight: 80,
  )
```

View to render post with image

```
<div id="userindex">
   <% img.each do |link| %>
      <div>
          <%= image_tag(link) %>
      </div>
   <% end %>                 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to learn why this happens, please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/11114634/2649456

Change your script to:

```
jQuery -> //when dom is ready
  $(".my-class").justifiedGallery(
    lastRow : 'justify',
    captions: false,
    randomize: false,
    rowHeight: 80,
  )
```

And your html code to:

```
<div id="userindex" class="my-class">
   <% img.each do |link| %>
      <div>
          <%= image_tag(link) %>
      </div>
   <% end %>                 
</div>
```

Comment: Didnt saw that one. but this fix the problem. thanks!