# Autocomplete Typehead only working for the first input in the table

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have strange problem, Im using typehead autocomplete in datatable but it works only for the first input field in the first row but not working for the other below

```
     {data: 'vendor_id',render: function (data) {

       var path = "{{ route('autocompletevendor') }}";
      $('#type1').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (mydata) {
        return process(mydata);
            });
          }
        })
               return ('<input type="text" id="type1" onClick="this.select();" value="'+data+'">');   

   }},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This happens because all ids are expected to be unique in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114622/jquery-id-selector-works-only-for-the-first-element).  Use a class selector to ensure you get all the inputs with your jQuery selector:

```
{data: 'vendor_id',render: function (data) {

       var path = "{{ route('autocompletevendor') }}";
      $('.type1').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (mydata) {
        return process(mydata);
            });
          }
        })
               return ('<input type="text" class="type1" onClick="this.select();" value="'+data+'">');   

   }},
```

Comment: Thank you sir, But I have problem when I click on the next or search in the datatable, autocomplete function doesn't work for the input field, why?

Comment: I would open another question for that.  Also, it would now be helpful if you could replicate the issue into a plunkr or jsfiddle.

Comment: here to solve it
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on('click', "#vendor", function(){
    var path = "{{ route('autocompletevendor') }}";
                $('.vendor').typeahead({
                    source:  function (query, process) {
                        return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (mydata) { return process(mydata); });
                     }
                });
                });


</script>