# Calculate values of multiple fields and display for every row in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

I have an invoice which is not a table but inside a div in html are some input fields. These fields are being created dynamically by clicking on a button.

```
<li><input type="text" id="cost[]" name="unit[]" value="<?php echo $val->unit ; ?>"> </li>
<li><input type="text" id="qty[]" name="rate[]" value="<?php echo $val->rate ; ?>"> </li>
<li><input type="text" id="price[]" name="total[]" value="<?php echo $val->total ; ?>"> </li>
```

Now I want to multiply unit with rate and display it in the total field.

My Javascript is

```
 window.onkeyup=function() {

        var str = document.getElementById("cost[]").value;
        var str1 = document.getElementById("qty[]").value;
        var price = parseFloat(str*str1);
        document.getElementById("price[]").value = price;
}
```

The javascript above works fine but it works only for the first row. For the rest of the rows below the first row, it does not work. I want the calculation for all the rows. I have seen some of the answers but none of them works in my case.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns only one item. You should not have more than one HTML element with the same `id`. You should use classes instead, and then use `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Do you need something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/s79my99a/1/

Comment: No this is not what I want. I tried that way as well but it does not seem to working.

Comment: No, it does not work.

Comment: you cannot provide `id` attribute as array or you cannot have multiple elements with same id that is why it only picks the first one try changing the id to unique or add a class and then pick all the elements with that class name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery id selector works only for the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114622/jquery-id-selector-works-only-for-the-first-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I observe from your code is that you might be using same ids for multiple items.

The "id" attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

Though we have a workaround like:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id='someID']");
```

to select all elements with same "id"s, your HTML will be invalid.

And this is why we have "class" instead. A class is a group of elements.

Though I have used "name" attribute.

May be what you are looking for:

```js
 window.onkeyup=function() {
 
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
var itemsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(items,0);
var unit, rate, total, net = 0;
itemsArray.forEach(function(el){
 unit = el.querySelector('input[name="unit[]"]').value;
 rate = el.querySelector('input[name="rate[]"]').value;
 total = unit * rate;
 el.querySelector('input[name="total[]"]').value = total;
 net+=total;
});
document.getElementById('net').value=net;
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>
 <li><input type="text"  name="unit[]" value=""> </li>
 <li><input type="text"  name="rate[]" value=""> </li>
 <li><input type="text" name="total[]" value=""> </li>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class='item'>
 <li><input type="text" name="unit[]" value=""> </li>
 <li><input type="text" name="rate[]" value=""> </li>
 <li><input type="text" name="total[]" value=""> </li>
</div>

</br></br>

<li><input id='net' type="text" name="net[]" value=""> </li>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy..This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. :) 
You must learn how "id" and "class" attributes are used.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var invoices = document.querySelectorAll('.invoice')
var handleChange = function (foo, bar, total) {
 let str = +foo.value || 0
 let str2 = +bar.value || 0

  total.value = parseFloat(str*str2)
}

invoices.forEach(function(invoice) {
 
  var foo = invoice.querySelector('input[name=foo]')
  var bar = invoice.querySelector('input[name=bar]')
  var total = invoice.querySelector('input[name=total]')
  
  foo.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
   handleChange(foo, bar, total)
  })
  bar.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
   handleChange(foo, bar, total)
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="invoice">
  <input type="text" name="foo">
  <input type="text" name="bar">
  <input type="text" name="total">
</div>
<div class="invoice">
  <input type="text" name="foo" value="">
  <input type="text" name="bar" value="">
  <input type="text" name="total">
</div>
<div class="invoice">
  <input type="text" name="foo">
  <input type="text" name="bar">
  <input type="text" name="total">
</div>
<div class="invoice">
  <input type="text" name="foo">
  <input type="text" name="bar">
  <input type="text" name="total">
</div>
<div class="invoice">
  <input type="text" name="foo">
  <input type="text" name="bar">
  <input type="text" name="total">
</div>
```

Notice how i prepended a `+` to the parse of `str` & `str2` this operator turns any `String` number into a `Number`
I recommend you do this because when querying the value of a `input[type=text]` - it will give you the value represented as a `String`...

This is fine when multiplying e.g `'1'*'2'// = 2`...

But, if you want to `ADD` two numbers together, your sum will be interpreted  as concatenation e.g `'2'+'2' // = '22'`

It may also be smart to default your values to 0 if a value is not provided or a Alphabetic or special character is put into the input e.g `'hello'*'2' // = NaN`

try

`var str = +foo.value || 0;`

`var str1 = +bar.value || 0;`

`var price = parseFloat(str*str1);`

Alternatively, make your input `type="number"` this will limit the user to only be able to input numbers.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP said that the `cost[]` and `qty[]` fields can happen to repeat multiple times. The total must be the sum of all those fields.

Comment: Didnt read the Question carefully enough. Have ammended my code.

Answer (score 0):

As I've stated before, It's not recommended to keep multiple elements with the same `id` on your HTML. But if you want to keep things that way, then you can make use of `document.querySelectorAll` and iterate over the elements to sum their value and store it in the total:

```js
window.onkeyup=function() {

  var costs = document.querySelectorAll("input[id='cost[]'");
  var qtys = document.querySelectorAll("input[id='qty[]'");
  
  var price = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < costs.length; i++){
   price += +costs[i].value + +qtys[i].value;
  }

  document.getElementById("price[]").value = price;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cost[]" name="unit[]" value="2">
<input type="text" id="qty[]" name="rate[]" value="4">
<br>
<input type="text" id="cost[]" name="unit[]" value="2">
<input type="text" id="qty[]" name="rate[]" value="4">
<br>
<input type="text" id="cost[]" name="unit[]" value="2">
<input type="text" id="qty[]" name="rate[]" value="4">
<br>
<input type="text" id="cost[]" name="unit[]" value="2">
<input type="text" id="qty[]" name="rate[]" value="4">

<input type="text" id="price[]" name="total[]" value="">
```