# when i clicked on delete button it only ask for first id. after next id don't ask confirmation box why?

Tags: javascript

This is blade.php code

```
 <a id="delProduct" href="{{ url('/admin/delete-product/'.$product->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini">Delete</a>
```

This is javascript code

```
 $("#delProduct").click(function(){
    if(confirm('Are you sure want to delete this Product ?')){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: you should use classes instead of ID's: [info](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/#article-header-id-1)

Comment: A ID (identifier) needs to be unique. Your query for `$('#delProduct')` targets only the first element with that ID found. As @qjnr said, use a class instead. After that, `.click` shouldn't be used. Use `.on` instead `$('.delProduct').on('click', function() {...});`

Comment: You have a single `<a>` and a single click event for that `<a>`.  What "next id" are you referring to?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Why did you tag MySQL? MySQL has nothing to do with your problem. This is a JavaScript question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery id selector works only for the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114622/jquery-id-selector-works-only-for-the-first-element)

Answer (score 2):

You should use classes instead of ID's.
*From CSS-Tricks.com:*

> *ID's are unique*
>
> - Each element can have only one ID
> - **Each page can have only one element with that ID**
>
> *Classes are NOT unique*
>
> - **You can use the same class on multiple elements.**
> - You can use multiple classes on the same element.

Your selector (`#delProduct`) only targets the first element found with the specified ID, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11114634/8649828).