# I put <form> tag in my template into a for loop to show 5-star-rating for each image and user can rate but its only saving response of 1st element

Tags: javascript, django, for-loop, rating

i try to make a website with different images and user can give 5=-star-rating to them so i save the images from admin side and place a card into loop to show all the present data from database and with that i also place 5-star- rate to give rating but it saving the data of 1st image only in the card i want it to save rating of each image, i search it everywhere but cant find any solution please help me with this.

**This is my HTML page**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {%for a in ab%}
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{a.image.url}}">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{a.product}}</h5>
                     <div class="col text-center">
                    <form class="rate-form" action="" method="POST" id="{{a.id}}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-3x my-btn" id="first"></button>
                        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-3x my-btn" id="second"></button>
                        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-3x my-btn" id="third"></button>
                        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-3x my-btn" id="fourth"></button>
                        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-3x my-btn" id="fifth"></button>
                    </form>
                    <br>
                    <div id="confirm-box"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {%endfor%}
    </div>
    </div>
```

**This is my java-script**

```
// console.log('hello world')

// get all the stars
const one = document.getElementById('first')
const two = document.getElementById('second')
const three = document.getElementById('third')
const four = document.getElementById('fourth')
const five = document.getElementById('fifth')

// get the form, confirm-box and csrf token
const form = document.querySelector('.rate-form')
const confirmBox = document.getElementById('confirm-box')
// const csrf = document.getElementsByName('CsrfViewMiddleware')
var csrf = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();


const handleStarSelect = (size) => {
    const children = form.children
    console.log(children[0])
    for (let i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if(i <= size) {
            children[i].classList.add('checked')
        } else {
            children[i].classList.remove('checked')
        }
    }
}

const handleSelect = (selection) => {
    switch(selection){
        case 'first': {
            // one.classList.add('checked')
            // two.classList.remove('checked')
            // three.classList.remove('checked')
            // four.classList.remove('checked')
            // five.classList.remove('checked')
            handleStarSelect(1)
            return
        }
        case 'second': {
            handleStarSelect(2)
            return
        }
        case 'third': {
            handleStarSelect(3)
            return
        }
        case 'fourth': {
            handleStarSelect(4)
            return
        }
        case 'fifth': {
            handleStarSelect(5)
            return
        }
        default: {
            handleStarSelect(0)
        }
    }

}

const getNumericValue = (stringValue) =>{
    let numericValue;
    if (stringValue === 'first') {
        numericValue = 1
    } 
    else if (stringValue === 'second') {
        numericValue = 2
    }
    else if (stringValue === 'third') {
        numericValue = 3
    }
    else if (stringValue === 'fourth') {
        numericValue = 4
    }
    else if (stringValue === 'fifth') {
        numericValue = 5
    }
    else {
        numericValue = 0
    }
    return numericValue
}

if (one) {
    const arr = [one, two, three, four, five]

    arr.forEach(item=> item.addEventListener('mouseover', (event)=>{
        handleSelect(event.target.id)
    }))

    arr.forEach(item=> item.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
        // value of the rating not numeric
        const val = event.target.id
        
        let isSubmit = false
        form.addEventListener('submit', e=>{
            e.preventDefault()
            if (isSubmit) {
                return
            }
            isSubmit = true
            // picture id
            const id = e.target.id
            // value of the rating translated into numeric
            const val_num = getNumericValue(val)

            $.ajax({
                url: '/add_rating/',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf,
                    'el_id': id,
                    'val': val_num,
                },
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response)
                    confirmBox.innerHTML = `<h1>Successfully rated with ${response.score}</h1>`
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error)
                    confirmBox.innerHTML = '<h1>Ups... something went wrong</h1>'
                }
            })
        })
    }))
}
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(".btnrating").on('click',(function(e) {

    var previous_value = $("#selected_rating").val();

    var selected_value = $(this).attr("data-attr");
    $("#selected_rating").val(selected_value);

    $(".selected-rating").empty();
    $(".selected-rating").html(selected_value);

    for (i = 1; i <= selected_value; ++i) {
    $("#rating-star-"+i).toggleClass('btn-warning');
    $("#rating-star-"+i).toggleClass('btn-default');
    }

    for (ix = 1; ix <= previous_value; ++ix) {
    $("#rating-star-"+ix).toggleClass('btn-warning');
    $("#rating-star-"+ix).toggleClass('btn-default');
    }

    }));
});
```

Comment: `id`s must be unique. You are not allowed to have more than one element with the ID `first`, `second`, …

Comment: `id="first"`, etc. and `id="confirm-box"` you write these **in a loop**. But ids are supposed to be **unique** in the HTML. Furthermore your javascript doesn't appear to match much to your HTML, `.btnrating`? You don't have any elements with such a class, neither do you have `selected-rating`, etc.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat i am a beginner can you please tel me a solution i am not getting it properly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery id selector works only for the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114622/jquery-id-selector-works-only-for-the-first-element)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat problem is with my javascript or with my HTML page?