# Checked a checkbox based on another checkbox if checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel-blade

I have some checkboxes generating through a foreach loop. All I want, by checking one checkbox another checkbox will be checked. I have already tried something like this,

This is the foreach block where the checkboxes are generating.

```
@foreach($testItems->where('category_id', $category->id) as $item)
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class='form-check'>
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox"class="select-test form-check-input form-check-secondary" id="selectTest" name="test_name" value="{{$item->test_name}}">
      </div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="price" id="testPrice" name="test_price" value="{{$item->price}}" >
      <span>{{ucwords($item->test_name)}} ( {{$item->price}} )</span>
   </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

This is the script I tried

```
  var chk1 = $("#selectTest");
  var chk2 = $("#testPrice");
  chk1.on('change',  function(){
  chk2.prop('checked',this.checked);
  });
```

in this case, the first checkbox only works fine, but rest of them are not working.

Comment: how are you supposed to target each one seperately if they all have the same `id=""` ? which is not valid html by the way.

Comment: Can you add an example of the `html` that you get?

Comment: id should be different for each element

Comment: there are two different id. one is id="selectTest" and other one is id="testPrice" @N69S

Comment: @DebjitPaul , much as they are different, more ***similar*** `id=` attributes get generated since your HTML markup is in a `@foreach` loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery ID selector works only for the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114622/jquery-id-selector-works-only-for-the-first-element)

Comment: yes, now i got it. Thanks @steven7mwesigwa

Answer (score -1):

It only works for the first checkbox **only** because `id=` attributes only match the first matching node in the DOM. Use a class (`.selectTest`) instead.

You may need to get rid of `id="testPrice"` as well or make it a class instead.

```html
@foreach($testItems->where('category_id', $category->id) as $item)
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class='form-check'>
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox"class="select-test form-check-input form-check-secondary selectTest" name="test_name" value="{{$item->test_name}}">
      </div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="price" name="test_price" value="{{$item->price}}" >
      <span>{{ucwords($item->test_name)}} ( {{$item->price}} )</span>
   </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

The jquery script.

```js
 var chk1 = $(".selectTest");

  chk1.on('change',  function(){

      $(this).closest("div").next().prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));

  });
```

[id attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

> The `id` [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) defines an identifier (ID) which must be
> unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element
> when linking (using a [fragment identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Identifying_resources_on_the_Web#fragment)), scripting, or styling
> (with [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS)).