# Can't hide element when empty

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="url" class="infoline">
  <i class="fa fa-link fa-2x fa-fw coloriconfa"></i>
  <a href="<?=$data['post']['url']?>" target="_blank"><?=$data['post']['url']?></a>                     
</div>
```

Hide searches with this function JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#url").each(function() {

    if($.trim($(this).html()).length == '') {
       $(this).hide();
    };
 });
});
```

Help me please

Comment: You're checking `.length` to an empty string, should be `.length == 0`

Comment: I think you want `.text()`, not `.html()`. `.html()` will include all the nested tags.

Comment: There's no need to use `.each()`. IDs have to be unique, so there's nothing to loop over.\

Comment: I want to hide the whole <div> with id="url" if it doesn't contain any data

Comment: @ShvetZz then you need to check if the `a` tag in the div is empty, not the entire `#url` div, which has children.

Comment: @Phix Yes, you are right) Everything turned out! Here's the resulting code: '$("#ur").each(function() {

        if($.trim($(ur).html()).length == 0) {
           $(url).hide();
        };
    
    });'

Comment: To clarify, [jQuery ID selector works only for the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114622/jquery-id-selector-works-only-for-the-first-element).

Answer (score 0):

A friend @Phix suggested a solution and it worked!

```
<div id="url" class="infoline">
  <i class="fa fa-link fa-2x fa-fw coloriconfa"></i>
  <a id="ur" href="<?=$data['post']['url']?>" target="_blank"><?=$data['post']['url']?></a>                     
</div>
```

Tweaked

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    if($.trim($(ur).html()).length == 0) {
       $(url).hide();
    };
});
```

I had to add an id for line a, but this is tolerable)