# What is missing on this JS code to make it looping

Tags: javascript

What is missing on this basic code to make it looping when the prompt input give error?

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var error = "Error. You should input rock, paper or scissors!";
var inputAgain = "Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?";
    if(userChoice!=="rock") {
        if(userChoice!=="paper") {
            if(userChoice!=="scissors") {
                confirm(error);
                userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to add an outer loop so that until you meet some success criterion, it will keep looping.

Comment: A .. loop is missing.

Comment: @JaredFarrish are you suggesting the two prompts with the same message have the appearance of a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised the compiler did not detect the `Again` part of the variable name `inputAgain` and figure out that you wanted it to do a loop.

Anyway, recursion is often a good way to loop!

```
function keep_asking() {
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    var error = "Error. You should input rock, paper or scissors!";
    if(userChoice!=="rock") {
        if(userChoice!=="paper") {
            if(userChoice!=="scissors") {
                confirm(error);
                return keep_asking();
            }
        }
    }
    return userChoice;
]
```

In ES6 there is tail recursion, so doing things this way is "free".

Answer (score 1):

```
var requiredValues = ["rock","paper","scissors"];
while(requiredValues.indexOf(prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?"))<0){
    alert("Error. You should input rock, paper or scissors!");
}
```

Comment: This is like the worst code a person could write... Not human-readable, creating a new array instances every time, not even comments on there...

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 This code (written when it was the previous code) isn't that bad, although I would separate the prompt from the condition for readability. Also, "creating a new array" is entirely irrelevant in terms of any performance implication here.

Comment: There's some poor choices made, but this doesn't even crack the Top 50 worst code examples I've seen in some answers on this site.

Comment: if you assign prompt(...) to a variable, then the result we be able to be used after the loop... ie `requiredValues.indexOf(userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?"))`

Comment: Agreed with Jared, in fact this is rather concise, which improves readability.  Compare this 3-liner with brunt's answer and you'll know what's going on in a quarter of the time here.  Plus, by making the possible values in an array, it adds scalability for when more values are needed (e.g., `bomb`, `ray gun`,`atomic bomb`).  I'll add that br3nt is adding more, but he's also right above, assign the result.

Comment: Can't use this because i haven't learned the 'while' yet but i need to  do exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a loop so that the question can continue to be asked and answered.

```
var options = ["rock","paper","scissors"],
    userChoice;

while (true) {
    userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

    // stop asking if answer is valid
    if (options.indexOf(userChoice.trim().toLowerCase()) >= 0) break;

    // otherwise, inform user of error and continue asking
    confirm("Error. You should input rock, paper or scissors!");
}
```

Comment: not a big fan of `do..while`  would rather see this just as a `while`, especially since you've initialized ask_question to a value that will make the loop perform at least once

Comment: I'd also add a `toLowerCase()` and `trim()` as minimum precaution to reduce user error

Comment: ditto... lol.  Though the purpose of `do..while` is to loop at least once.  In this instance we want to ask rock, paper, scissors at least once.

Comment: I would also extract our the conditional into a separate method.

Comment: still saying that because your initial condition is always going to evaluate to `true`, you don't need the extra markup of the `do`, just place `while` at the top

Comment: Using *true..break* is very clunky, you should have an actual condition that is tested, e.g. something like `while (!(/rock|paper|scissors/i.test(userChoice))) {...}`.

Comment: @RobG, It's rather subjective.  Check out [this accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6850411/848668).  If you look through my edits, you'll see I've done exactly what that answer suggests.  The whole thread has some good comments for both sides of the argument.  If anything, I should get rid of the `if..else`, in my opinion.  Infact, I'll do that... lol

Comment: There... next thing would be to factor out the input validation into a separate method.  `if (user_input_valid(userChoice)) break;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var funcAskUserChoice=function(){
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

    // click prompt cancel
    if(userChoice === null){
        return;
    }

    // input is correct
    if(userChoice === "rock" || userChoice === "paper" || userChoice === "scissors"){
        return;
    }

    // click confirm cancel
    if(confirm("Error. You should input rock, paper or scissors!") === false){
        return;
    }

    // ask again
    funcAskUserChoice();
}

// start loop
funcAskUserChoice();
```

[** DEMO **](http://jsfiddle.net/jckim0414/sjefo807/2)