# Loop and half VS repeat-until-sentinel idiom

Tags: java, computer-science

At university we learned 2 ways to read integers from console, while specific integer is not given.
First one is the "Loop and half":

```
int val = readInt(“Enter val:”);
while (val != SENTINEL) 
    val = readInt(“Enter val:”);
}
```

They say that it is a bad way because of code duplication  `val = readInt(“Enter val:”);` 
and they suggest second way to do it "The Repeat-Until-Sentinel Idiom" :

```
  while (true) {
       value = readInt(“Enter val:”);
       if (value == sentinel) break;
    }
```

I had teacher,who was more in computer science and he always sad that its better to avoid `while(true)` and `break` in programs and don't use them unless emergency, so i am little confused now. 
Which way is considered as a better solution ?

Comment: **readInt()?** are you sure you are using core Java library?

Comment: This is entirely a matter of opinion. You can read arguments for and against both sides. As an opinion-based question, this question is considered off-topic for SO

Comment: @KickButtowski That's irrelevant to the question. The meaning of `readInt()` is obvious, even assuming that it is a custom method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem with what you refer to as "Loop and half" is that there is a little code duplication.  The reason why the one you call "Repeat-Until-Sentinel" is not ideal is that the idiom `while(true)` is not very expressive of your intent.  See [Are “while(true)” loops so bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850380/are-whiletrue-loops-so-bad) for another explanation.

In your example, you could do

```
int value;
while ((value = readInt()) != SENTINEL) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

In java, when you have an assignment operation, the result is returned, so you can compare it without duplicating your code.

The important aspect is that it's more expressive of the intent: You can kind of read it as *while the value read is not the sentinel*.

Answer (score 1):

How about a third solution?

```
boolean keepReading = true;
while (keepReading) {
    int val = readInt("Enter val");
    if (val == SENTINEL) {
        keepReading = false;
    } 
    else {
        // process the value
    }
}
```

It's similar to the second one, but doesn't use `while(true)` and `break`. I really don't like the first one, because to make it complete, you also have to repeat the check against the sentinel:

```
int val = readInt(“Enter val:”);
while (val != SENTINEL) 
    val = readInt(“Enter val:”); // duplication
    if (val != SENTINEL) { // duplication
        // process the value 
    }
}
```

Comment: @KickButtowski I definitely prefer Potato. Potato is old school, really :)

Comment: Personally I'd go with Potato.  Some things never go out of style.