# Blank 'For' Loop Giving Output

Tags: c

I encountered a strange `FOR LOOP` question in the book. Here is the code for the loop -

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i=1,j=1;
for(;;)
  {
    if(i>5)
        break;
    else
        j+=i;
    printf("%d\n",j);
    i+=j;
  }
return 0;
}
```

The program prints `2` & `5` as the output. Now could anyone please explain how this `for` loop is executing?

Comment: You could use a debugger to find out how this executes.

Comment: You could also use a search engine. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Use_as_infinite_loops and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Iteration_statements ("Any of the three expressions in the for loop may be omitted")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That for loop is a classic idiom for a non-terminating loop. It's what you use when you want a loop that never terminates, or whose termination is controlled by control flow statements inside the loop. The latter is the case here.

```
for(;;)
```

All parts of the `for` loop are empty. They key to understanding why it is a non-terminating loop is the empty controlling expression in the `for` statement.

The standard (**6.8.5.3 The for statement**) says, with my emphasis:

> The statement
>
> ```
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
> ```
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling
>   expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
>   The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after
>   each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a declaration, the
>   scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the
>   declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions;
>   it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of
>   the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is
>   evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the
>   controlling expression.158)
>
> Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. **An omitted
>   expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant**.

And this means that your loop will never terminate due to the controlling expression part of the `for` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(;;)
```

is a `for` loop which performs no initialisation, has no exit condition and performs no post-action.

It will loop forever unless code inside the loop contains a condition that can result in `break` being called.

Your loop is equivalent to

```
int i,j;
for(i=1, j=1 ;i<=5 ;i+=j) {
    j+=i;
    printf("%d\n",j);
}
```

Comment: Fair Enough. Does it mean that the condition part has some non zero value so that it is running infinitely?

Comment: @PranavJituri Yes it does. The standard says that.

Answer (score 2):

`for(;;)` is equivalent to `while(true)` (or `while(1)` in old-school C), both of whose terminations are only controlled by the statements inside them.

---

**Edit**:
To rehash a couple of old jokes (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401159/for-or-while-true-which-is-the-correct-c-sharp-infinite-loop/1401207#1401207)):

1. Don't use `for (;;) {}` — it makes the statement cry.
2. Unless, of course, you `#define EVER ;;`.

Comment: @PranavJituri In other words, `while (true)` is a bit more readable than `for (;;) {}`. :)

Comment: Aah. That is true mate.

Comment: On the other hand, in old-school C, there is no true and you'd write while (1)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could you tell me why is this in old-school C? I don't find any resource about this.

Comment: @hero Early versions of C did not have a boolean data type.